# Overwriting bang methods with Rails enums

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

I'm using enum in a model, and I want to overwrite the bang method, e.g.:

```
class Foo < Application Record
  enum status: [:ok, :error]

  def ok!
    self.error_message = nil
    super
  end
end
```

Testing this, it works fine.  Are there any potential pitfalls?

Alternatively, is it better/cleaner to skip super altogether:

```
def ok!
  self.update_attributes(status: :ok, error_message: nil)
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: update: I realized that calling `super` caused some issues if I wanted to pass arguments to the new method, so I think I've decided to be explicit and call ``save`` or ``save!`` etc. as needed.

Comment: You could have used `super()` instead of `super` in order not to pass any argument to the original `ok!` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on what you want to do.  Calling `super` will update the attribute using the `update!` method which will throw an exception if there is a validation problem.

Conversely, calling `self.update_attributes(status: :ok)` will return `false` if there is a validation failure, but it will not throw an exception.

For consistency, I recommend `super`, but it all depends on how you want validation problems to be handled.

NOTE: This was based on reviewing the [Rails 5.1 enum source code](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) and has been tested in Rails 5.1.

Comment: +1 for pointing out validation and return value differences.  As per my updated comment I also realized there are issues when passing in args.  So I'm going to avoid ``super`` for now and be explicit with any overriding methods.